# Access iframe contents, javascript; won't work on webkit

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, webkit

So I'm trying to get the contents of an Iframe using Jquery; it works on Firefox and Opera but when I tried it on another webkit browser (namely the Ubuntu Phone Browser) this code returned null:

$("f").contents().find("title").html();

Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you use $("f") and not $("iframe")?

Comment: What returns null? .html()? that means .find("title") didn't find anything. Debug that first.

Comment: Explain what you try? With full code ?